# order of the data is not proper nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am bit new to nodejs. I am building a facebook like application. Anyway, I am querying the database as shown in the code. but order of the records I `console.log` on the front end is jumbled and not proper and everytime is different. Can you please tell me where am I mistaking?

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    var friendsIds = req.user.friends;
    friendsIds.push(req.user.id);
    var cbdone = 0;

    Status.find({statuserId : {$in: friendsIds}}, null, {skip : 0, limit: 5, sort: {_id: -1}}, function(err, statuses) {

        for (var i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) {
            (function(currStatus){
                var currentStatus = currStatus;
                var a = currentStatus._id.getTimestamp();
                if(currentStatus.likedBy){
                    if (currentStatus.likedBy.indexOf(req.user.id) > -1) {
                        currentStatus.isLiked = true;
                    };
                    currentStatus.likersCount = currentStatus.likedBy.length;
                } else {
                    currentStatus.isLiked = false;
                    currentStatus.likersCount = 0;
                }

                Comment.find({statusId : currentStatus.id}, null, {sort: {_id: -1}}, function(err, comments){
                    for (var i = comments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        comments[i].likersCount = comments[i].likedBy.length;
                        comments[i].isLiked = comments[i].likedBy.indexOf(req.user.id) > -1;
                    };
                    currentStatus.comments = comments;
                    cbdone++;
                    if(cbdone === statuses.length){
                        res.render('home2', {
                            user: req.user, 
                            statuses: statuses
                        }); 
                    }
                });

            })(statuses[i]);            
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: What I see is a bit of false schema design, you shouldn't have the comment collection, you should embed the comments as an array in the statuses collection, in this way you will reduce the amount of requests to the database drastically

Comment: But a row of the mongodb document has some size limits and comments can keep growing. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yep the threshold size of an document is 16mb, you should get a lot of comments to make it, any way you would register the images in a gridfs and your documents seldomly would exceed mb

Answer (score 0):

You should use Promise.all or Promise + co or async/await to make your aync calls' result in order.

```
Status.find({statuserId : {$in: friendsIds}}, null, {skip : 0, limit: 5, sort: {_id: -1}}, function (err, statuses) {
  co(function *() {
    const Comments = yield statuses.map(function (currentStatus) {
      var currentStatus = currStatus;
      var a = currentStatus._id.getTimestamp();
      if(currentStatus.likedBy){
        if (currentStatus.likedBy.indexOf(req.user.id) > -1) {
          currentStatus.isLiked = true;
        };
        currentStatus.likersCount = currentStatus.likedBy.length;
      } else {
        currentStatus.isLiked = false;
        currentStatus.likersCount = 0;
      }
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Comment.find({statusId : currentStatus.id}, null, {sort: {_id: -1}}, function(err, comments){
          if(err) return reject(err);
          for (var i = comments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            comments[i].likersCount = comments[i].likedBy.length;
            comments[i].isLiked = comments[i].likedBy.indexOf(req.user.id) > -1;
          };
          resolve(comments);
        });
      })
    });
 ......
    res.render('home2', {
      user: req.user,
      statuses: statuses
    });
  })

});
```